# How to group two arrays in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents `books`:

```
{
  title: "My book",
  authors: [{id: 1, date: "2023-12-20"},{id: 2, date: "2023-12-21"}],
  authorsDetails: [{id: 2, name:"Author 2", age: 25}, {id: 1, name: "Author 1", age: 38}],
}
```

I need to do an aggregation and the result must return the following result:

```
{
  title: "My book",
  authors: [{id: 1, date: "2023-12-20", name: "Author 1"},{id: 2, date: "2023-12-21", name: "Author 2"}],
}
```

Basically I need to add some informations from `authorsDetails` to `authors`. In this case only the name.

NOTE: The two arrays are not necessary sorted in the same way.

I tried an `$addFields` pipe + `$map` but it is not enough. I tried this:

```
const pipeline = [
    //...
    {
      $addFields: {
        indices: { $range: [0, { $size: '$authors' }] },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        admins: {
          $map: {
            input: '$indices',
            as: 'index',
            in: {
              detail: { $arrayElemAt: ['$authorsDetails', '$$index'] },
              author: { $arrayElemAt: ['$authors', '$$index'] },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    //...
]
```

This works only if the arrays are sorted in the same way. Also I need to do another map to fix this as I expect.

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you ensure the ids in both arrays are one to one? i.e. one author will always corresponds to only one authorDetails and there are no missing entries.

Comment: Yes i confirm that. There is always the corresponding id in both arrays. Consider that is the result of a lookup @ray

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FwOzZINeWFz
not sure if the best tho. i first wrote in js and then coverted to mongo syntax

Comment: I put a answer based on your current input. But I guess that you are having this structure from some pipeline stages. It might be easier to wrangle the data at the `$lookup` stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that the ids in 2 arrays are 1 to 1 correspondence(i.e. the id in author will only map to 1 entry in authorDetails Array and there is no missing/duplicate entry), we can first `$sortArray` to align the entries. Then use `$zip` and `$mergeObjects` to combine the array entries.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "authors": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$authors",
          "sortBy": {
            "id": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "authorsDetails": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$authorsDetails",
          "sortBy": {
            "id": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "authors": {
        "$zip": {
          "inputs": [
            "$authors",
            "$authorsDetails"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "authors": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$authors",
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              {
                $first: "$$a"
              },
              {
                $last: "$$a"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "authorsDetails"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2hZQq7FzUGX)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach where you `$concatArrays` first , then you can `$unwind` the new array and `$group` back together based on `authors.id` and then `$mergeObjects` within that `$group` stage. I had to do another `$group` stage to keep hold of that `title` but it does the job. Hopefully someone sees a more efficient way so that it can be improved.

Key point here is you don't need to rely on any sorting.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      authors: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$authors",
          "$authorsDetails"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$authors"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$authors.id",
        title: "$title"
      },
      authors: {
        $mergeObjects: "$authors"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.title",
      authors: {
        $push: "$authors"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      title: "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "_id",
      "authors.age"
    ]
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ViprZJoqkmq) for a working example.